# Função random retorna números maiores que os definidos

Tags: javascript

Fiz uma função que deveria retornar um número `random` entre 0 e 50, porém está retornando números maiores que 50.

```
function random(){
    var random = Math.random(0, 50)
    var resultado = random * 100
    alert(parseInt(resultado))
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A função `Math.random()` retorna um número pseudo-aleatório no intervalo `[0, 1[` [MDN - Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Esse intervalo corresponde ao mesmo que `0 <= Math.random() < 1`, ou seja esse função retorna de zero (incluindo o zero) a um número real menor que 1.

Exemplos de números retornados na função `Math.random()`:

```
0.9846826303988312
0.2173987016086012
0.30711801525592763
0.00979063791034318
0.6827624772816574
```

Para obter um número maior do que os retornados pelo `Math.random()`, deve-se multiplicar o retorno deste método por um número natural maior que 1.

```
Math.random() * 50
```

Resultados:

```
32.593616844490846
1.3650244020898872
49.12502614593396
8.921204790246563
19.29410180999559
```

Se deseja obter um número inteiro você usar o método `Math.round()` .

> A função `Math.round()`retorna o valor de um número arredondado para o inteiro mais proximo. [MDN - Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```
Math.round(Math.random() * 50)
```

Resultados:

```
8
13
48
29
40
```

---

Resolvendo o problema:

O que deve fazer para resolver o seu problema é retirar os paramentros do `Math.random()` e multiplicar por 50 ao inves de 100, dessa forma só retornará números menores que 50, logo após, usa `Math.round()` para arredondaro valor e permitir que haja um intervalo de 0 a 50.

```js
function random() {
    var random = Math.random() * 50;
    return Math.round(random);
}

alert(random());
```

Comment: Com floor nunca vai chegar em 50. E seria melhor que função retornasse o número, não?

Comment: Corrigi isso usando o round.

Comment: Coloque os dois códigos(`floor` e `round`) e explique a diferenças, o porque um funciona com intervalo aberto a direita e o outro código funciona com intervalo fechado a direita. Vai agregar mais valor a resposta. variável random é desnecessária.